# Qual a análise sintática de "Viver é lutar"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, verbos, sintaxe, análise-sintática

No período "Viver é lutar", como analisar sintaticamente os três verbos? Temos orações reduzidas ou verbos no infinitivo analisados como nomes? Nesse período, qual a oração principal?

Comment: Diego, francamente, eu não sei o que falar mais. Acho que justifiquei bastante a minha resposta a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Uma oração apenas, com verbos no infinitivo analisados como substantivos.  O sujeito é `viver`, e o verbo é o verbo `ser`.

Para que tivéssemos diversas "*orações*" neste período, precisaríamos ter conjunções unindo as orações (e não um verbo); neste caso, é bem claro que o que une `viver` a `lutar` é um verbo, o verbo `ser` (`é`). Além do mais, cada oração necessitaria de um sujeito (mesmo que sujeitos ocultos); no entanto, em `Viver é lutar`, não se menciona quem vive ou quem luta, mas é feita uma generalização, comparando o ato de viver com o de lutar.

Answer (score -1):

> *O olhar* era misterioso.
> Atendo-nos ao termo em destaque, *infere-se tratar de um verbo*, o
> qual indica uma ação. Nesse sentido, temos que esse termo, mantendo-se
> intacto (abstendo-se de acréscimos ou supressões), passou a ocupar
> outra classe gramatical, ou seja, **de verbo passou a substantivo**,
> tendo em vista um contexto específico.
>
> [...]

- **O vocábulo substantivado pode ocupar funções sintáticas distintas, como por exemplo, a de sujeito e de complemento**. Perceba: O não já foi dito. (sujeito) / Preciso dizer um sim. (objeto direto) [Esse é diferente do exemplo na pergunta.]
  [substantivação de vocábulo](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/entendendo-acerca-processo-substantivacao.html)

"**Viver é lutar**" = **palavra ou verbo substantivada seguido de um verbo de ligação (ser) seguido de um segundo verbo substantivado, que tambem poderia se dizer: complemento**. viver e lutar não funcionam como verbos. Funcionam como substantivos.

> Verbo “ser”
> **O verbo “ser” é um verbo de ligação entre sujeito e predicativo**. Dependendo da ênfase pretendida pelo enunciador, pode concordar tanto
> com o sujeito quanto com o predicativo. [ser- verbo de ligação](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/verbo-ser.htm)

Navegar é preciso; viver não é preciso (Fernando Pessoa)